databricks delta - dynamic replace where conditions
I am trying to use a replacewhere clause on delta tables using azure databricks. Here is the setup to recreate the issue:
CREATE TABLE mymaintable (dt DATE, name STRING, YN string) USING delta;

INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-01', 'N1', 'Y');
INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-01', 'N2', 'N');
INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-01', 'N3', 'Y');

INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-02', 'N1', 'N');
INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-02', 'N2', 'N');
INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-02', 'N3', 'N');

INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-03', 'N1', 'Y');
INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-03', 'N2', 'Y');
INSERT INTO mymaintable VALUES ('2024-03-03', 'N3', 'Y');

CREATE TABLE myincrementaltable (dt DATE, name STRING, YN string) USING delta;

INSERT INTO myincrementaltable VALUES ('2024-03-03', 'N1', 'X');
INSERT INTO myincrementaltable VALUES ('2024-03-03', 'N2', 'Z');
INSERT INTO myincrementaltable VALUES ('2024-03-04', 'Q1', 'X');
INSERT INTO myincrementaltable VALUES ('2024-03-04', 'Q2', 'Z');

this is the setup. Now I want to replacewhere the incremental table into the main table.
This works:
INSERT INTO mymaintable
REPLACE WHERE dt >= "2024-03-03"
TABLE myincrementaltable

but this does not:
INSERT INTO mymaintable
REPLACE WHERE dt >= (SELECT MAX(dt) from mymaintable)
TABLE myincrementaltable

it fails with the error:
AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `mymaintable` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.

Is there anyway to do this?

any spark configs to tweak?
or a way to pass the max date dynamically using a sql statement?

Thanks!

Can you try doing Variable (note use Runtime 14.1 or higher)?
DECLARE VARIABLE myvar DATE;

SET VAR myvar = (SELECT MAX(dt) from sandbox.mymaintable);

INSERT INTO sandbox.mymaintable
REPLACE WHERE dt >= myvar 
TABLE sandbox.myincrementaltable

Below you can find link to docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-variables

I am not sure of the direct SQL statement update, but I would try something below in a separate python cell
Var = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(dt) from sandbox.mymaintable").collect()[0][0]

SQLString = f"""
INSERT INTO sandbox.mymaintable
REPLACE WHERE dt >= '{Var}'
TABLE sandbox.myincrementaltable"""

spark.sql(SQLString)

Just a try. Hope it helps

Thanks! Yes, I think this should work as well as we are passing the date explicitly using python. However, would like to see if we can do this in pure SQL operations only.
